# Regex parsing issues of multi-line entries containing formatted text

Tags: java, xml, regex, hadoop, hive

I have an internal system log file which I have been parsing via and external Hive table and a Regex statement. But recently, issues in the output data have emerged with parts of the XML data incomplete in the Output result set. After further investigation, the issue is down to formatted text in the XML data being passed into the logs.
Traditionally, each log message is contained on a single line and the regex statement works fine but when a message contains formatted text, it pushes parts of the message onto one or more lines and so the XML data is chopped when parsed.
The issue I have is that I need to some how piece together the complete message back into one line so that the regex can successfully parse the whole message and not chop any data.

Below is sample of the data I am dealing with.

**Typical log message**

```
0 20130323212857832 20130323212857832 0000 006 00/0000/000 BPAGPRDAGA01   Lexkin   000 000000 00 Reply: 0ms 865b3926-9002-4506-9825-c72bf19e694c: <GetProgramIdResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetProgramIdResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Accounts.Responses" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ContactUs xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">false</ContactUs><ErrorDescription xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common"></ErrorDescription><ErrorMessage xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common"></ErrorMessage><ErrorNo xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">0</ErrorNo><ErrorSource xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">None</ErrorSource><ErrorTitle xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common"></ErrorTitle><ErrorType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">0</ErrorType><b:ProgramId>-1</b:ProgramId></GetProgramIdResult></GetProgramIdResponse>
```

**Message with formatted text 1**

```
0 20130323212857832 20130323212857832 0000 006 00/0000/000 BPAGPRDAGA01   Lexkin   000 000000 00 Reply: 0ms 865b3926-9002-4506-9825-c72bf19e694c: <GetProgramIdResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetProgramIdResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Accounts.Responses" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ContactUs xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">false</ContactUs><ErrorDescription xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">Issues with Core system,
Engineer support required</ErrorDescription><ErrorMessage xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common"></ErrorMessage><ErrorNo xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">0</ErrorNo><ErrorSource xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">None</ErrorSource><ErrorTitle xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common"></ErrorTitle><ErrorType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">0</ErrorType><b:ProgramId>-1</b:ProgramId></GetProgramIdResult></GetProgramIdResponse>
```

**Message with formatted text 2**

```
0 20130323212857832 20130323212857832 0000 006 00/0000/000 BPAGPRDAGA01   Lexkin   000 000000 00 Reply: 0ms 865b3926-9002-4506-9825-c72bf19e694c: <GetProgramIdResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetProgramIdResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Accounts.Responses" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ContactUs xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">false</ContactUs><ErrorDescription xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">Isuses with Core system,
Engineer support required</ErrorDescription><ErrorMessage xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common"></ErrorMessage><ErrorNo xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">0</ErrorNo><ErrorSource xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">Lexkin webservice,
Exception detected</ErrorSource><ErrorTitle xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common"></ErrorTitle><ErrorType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common">0</ErrorType><b:ProgramId>-1</b:ProgramId></GetProgramIdResult></GetProgramIdResponse>
```

**Regex Statement**
Due to the log file containing various log messages that are completely different format to each other, the complex regex statement below caters for all the messages types except for multi-line data

```
(^[0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+) (\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s+([^:]*): ([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)[ms]*(?<=[s ]) ?([0-9a-f-]*):? ?(.*)
```

So I am not sure what the best approach is to resolve this issue, some people have suggest writing a customer XML input format but my experience with input formats is amateur at best, hopefully this community can suggest other alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be the line-breaks inside the tags. Those are not captured by the `.` in the very last part of the regex. To have the `.` match newline characters you can set [single-line mode-modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

The thing with that is that `.*` then grabs everything [greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) which you wanna prevent, I would do it with a negative lookahead (i.e. grab everything that isn't followed by the beginning of this regex)

```
(^[0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+) (\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s+([^:]*): ([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)[ms]*(?!<=[s ]) ?([0-9a-f-]*):? ?((?:.(?![0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+))*)
```

**[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uS5kZ6/1) demo**

Comment: I had a look and tested your regex to ensure it handled all the different transactions types in the logs and so far so good. Hadoop uses java so I need to add the escapes but do I also have to specify the Modifier at the end of the regex statement? e.g. `/gms` in order for it to parse the data correctly.

Comment: I used RegexBuddy and it suggested I put `(?sm)` at the start of the Regex and when I test it on various online Regex tools, it matches the results as expected. The issue is in Hadoop when I try it in Hive table, it doesn't work correctly and match the data correctly, so I end up with a lot of NULL values in the result set.

Comment: Might it be that Hadoop already splits the entire file in separate lines? In that case the regex only gets fed the part of the log until the first line-break. See if you can modify the character-sequence Hadoop uses to split the lines, or disable splitting before regexing completely.

Comment: On further investigation, yes Hadoop does split the file into separate lines due to the way the log file is written by the logging tool. The regex statement works exactly as I expected but not with hadoop at the moment. I am working through another solution by possibly streaming the log data via Flume which means the Regex statement will then work. Thank you for your effort on this funkwurm